# jquery mobile - run function from another page without disable ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery-mobile

i have two page `test1.php` and `test2.php` when i click on my button for going to `test2.php` my function not running in `test2.php` only if i put `data-ajax="false"` in said button it working but i want without disable ajax .. Is there a way ?

> test1.php

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-
1.4.5.min.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js">
</script>
</head>
<body >
<div id="page-1" data-role="page" >
<div data-role="content">
<a href="test2.php">click</a>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

> test2.php

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-
1.4.5.min.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js">
</script>
</head>
<body >
<div id="page-1" data-role="page" >
<div data-role="content">
</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
 alert("hi");
})
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to run an external function, you can just create a file, let's call it myfunction.js. Then you add it below you jquery includes, like this:

```
...
<script src="//code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js">
<script src="myfunction.js"></script>
```

And in "myfunction.js" you add this:

```
$("a").click(function(){
  alert("Hi");
});
```

Kind of like I did in here: https://jsfiddle.net/uzt27mm2/ just call the script from an external .js file.

Comment: That's not the reason. Only a print error was modified. Do you think the reason for the page name is !!!!

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to do, so it's kind of hard to answer your question. All I'm seeing is you trying to trigger an alert box. All you have to do for that is just type: alert("Hi"); without the function part. So: <script>alert("hi");</script>

Comment: alert is just an example. A function where several programs must be implemented but this example only to be clear on who answers me

Comment: So you're trying to run a function when they click on the link?

Comment: yes i trying .. but function from test2.php not working because ajax

Comment: i want when i click on my button go to test2.php page and run my function on test2.php >>>my problem is when i go to another page my function not running because ajax page >>i wish understand my question